# How to show that the inverse function is $C^r, ~ r \ge 1$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n \in C^r(\mathbb{R}^n), ~ r\ge 1.$

Suppose that $\|Dg(x)\| < 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n.$

Define $f(x) = x + g(x).$

I can easily show that $f(x)$ defines a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^n$ on itself. But, How can I show that the inverse function is $C^r(\mathbb{R}^n)?$

It is a really interesting question that I cannot finish...

I am thinking also on a counter-example that shows that if $\|Dg(x)\| = 1$, for example, the statement does not hold. I appreciate any other examples to improve the exercise...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, all we need to check is, that $Df(x)$ is invertible for every $x$. We define

$$ B(x):= \sum_{k\geq 0} \left(- Dg(x) \right)^k.$$

First we check that the series does really converge. We use the fact that $\Vert Dg(x) \Vert <1$:

$$ \Vert \sum_{k\geq 0} \left( -Dg(x) \right)^k \Vert 
\leq  \sum_{k\geq 0} \Vert -Dg(x) \Vert^k = \frac{1}{1-\Vert Dg(x) \Vert} < \infty.$$

Next we check that $B(x)$ is the inverse of $Df(x)$:

$$Df(x) \circ B(x) = \left( I - (-Dg(x)) \right) \circ \sum_{k\geq 0} \left( -Dg(x) \right)^k  = \sum_{k\geq 0} \left( -Dg(x) \right)^k - \sum_{k\geq 1} \left( -Dg(x) \right)^k = I.$$

A similar calculation shows that $B(x) \circ Df(x)=I$. Hence, $Df(x)$ is invertible for every x and by the inverse function theorem we get that $f^{-1}$ is $C^r$.

Comment: @SeverinScraven, I do appreciate your calculation. Indeed, I did a similar thing, what I was wondering if is not enough to use that $\|Df(x)\| > 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where this comes from using the maximum norm?

Comment: You can only define $B(x)$ in the case where $\Vert Dg(x) \Vert\in [0, 1)$ otherwise the (geometric) series diverges.

Comment: yes, I am familiar with this. I appreciate too much your answer and enthusiasm doing all this calculation.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the $C^r$ inverse function theorem. How do you show that $Df(x)$ is nonsingular for any $x$? (This will explicitly use the assumption on the norm of $Dg(x)$.)

Comment: now I see, $Df(x) = I_d + Dg(x)$. Then $\|Df(x)\| \ge \|I_d\| - \|Dg(x)\| > 0.$

Comment: is this, right?

Comment: Absolutely right. :)

Comment: thank you! I really appreciate